# Storing Form Text Fields as Array within $_POST variable

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm creating an HTML form using jQuery that has certain text boxes grouped together under a single question (e.g., "List each URL that this request applies to.") For that question (and others), there are 3 text boxes below it along with a button to add additional text boxes if necessary.  When I pass this form data to be processed by PHP, how can I have all these text box values be grouped together as a single array variable within the $_POST array variable?  I tried giving all the text boxes the same name attribute followed by brackets, but that didn't seem to work (e.g., `<input name='myarray[]' type='text' />`). Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here are the specifics on the error I'm getting:

I'm using this in PHP

```
$myarray ='';
foreach ($_POST['myarray'] as $value) {
        $myarray .= $value . '\n';    
}
```

The error I get is:
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: It should work according to http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/form_processing.php.

Comment: What, exactly, didn't seem to work? You should have the post value in `$_POST['myarray']` as an array. Did you not get the values, or you got them and they failed to "save"? Are you submitting the form with jQuery as well, or just adding the inputs? To make a long story short - this should already work.

Comment: Are you accessing like this? `$_POST['myarray'][0]`

Comment: I'm accessing the array using the foreach method (see the addition I made to the post above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST["myarray"] as $myarray) 
{ 
     echo $myarray . ""; 
}
```

This is quite simple. I suppose you are using $_POST['myarray[]'] (notice brackets[]) which is incorrect. This example should work perfectly fine.